# efficient soultion to create multiple columns with formula. pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to create multiple columns(couple of hundreds) using values within the same df. is there a more efficient way for me to create multiple columns in batches? below is an example where i have to manually input new column names jwrl2_rank.r1, jwrl2_rank.1r1,jwrl2_rank.2r1, etc..  attached to the formula.

i0, i1, i2 are the original column names
and rn is the value within the column.

```
i0='jwrl2_rank'
i1='jwrl2_rank.1'
i2='jwrl2_rank.2'
i3='jwrl2_rank.3'
i4='jwrl2_rank.4'
i5='jwrl2_rank.5'
i6='jwrl2_rank.6'
i7='jwrl2_rank.7'

rn=1
df['jwrl2_rank.r1']=((df.loc[(df[i0]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i0]==rn),i0].count()))-1
df['jwrl2_rank.1r1']=((df.loc[(df[i1]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i1]==rn),i1].count()))-1
df['jwrl2_rank.2r1']=((df.loc[(df[i2]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i2]==rn),i2].count()))-1
df['jwrl2_rank.3r1']=((df.loc[(df[i3]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i3]==rn),i3].count()))-1
df['jwrl2_rank.4r1']=((df.loc[(df[i4]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i4]==rn),i4].count()))-1
df['jwrl2_rank.5r1']=((df.loc[(df[i5]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i5]==rn),i5].count()))-1
df['jwrl2_rank.6r1']=((df.loc[(df[i6]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i6]==rn),i6].count()))-1
df['jwrl2_rank.7r1']=((df.loc[(df[i7]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[i7]==rn),i7].count()))-1
```

many thanks. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a for loop should work.

### Incrementing string value

By using string interpolation you could solve your problem. See [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation) for a quick introduction. I am using `f-strings` in the example below.

```py
base_name='jwrl2_rank'
MAX_NUMBER = 3
for i in range(1, MAX_NUMBER + 1):
  new_name = f"{base_name}.{i}"
  print(new_name)
```

```
>>>
jwrl2_rank.1
jwrl2_rank.2
jwrl2_rank.3
```

### Example of for loop

```py
base_name='jwrl2_rank'
MAX_NUMBER = 3
for i in range(MAX_NUMBER + 1):
  current_iN = f"{base_name}.{i}"
  new_col_name = f"{base_name}.{i}r1"
  if i == 0: # compensate for missing zero in column name
    current_iN = base_name
    new_col_name = f"{base_name}.r1"

  df[new_col_name]=((df.loc[(df[current_iN]==rn)&(df['result']==1),'timing'].sum())/(df.loc[(df[current_iN]==rn),current_iN].count()))-1
```

Comment: thank you for the input. however, when i print(new name), only the last name(jwrl2_rank.3) shows. kindly advise .

Comment: This is the last set value to the variable `new_name`. You need to update your dataframe within the for loop.

Comment: sorry, could you show an example of the application within a loop, i'm still relative new at this? thank you

Comment: Added an example, I can not test it as I do not have access to the original dataframe.

Comment: the entire loops works out perfectly.  the f-strings you used made it very elegant! thank you very much.